# Removing sticky particle from sensor

Tags: sensor, cleaning, dust

I have two particles on the sensor of my Sony a6000. Both are round and about 0.3 mm in diameter.

The spots are only noticeable in bright areas and are easy to remove with Capture One's spot removal tool.

I looked up ways to clean my sensor and tried these:

- Blowing the particles carefully away with a hand blower
- Using the built-in clean mode

The particles didn't budge, though. I have thought about using a swab after reading about that but I'm anxious about damaging my sensor.

Am I safe to touch my sensor lightly with a swab to remove these particles?

Comment: You can always bring the camera to a professional to clean if you're anxious about cleaning it yourself.

Comment: @Matthew thanks. I probably misphrased that. I would totally try it with a swab but I don't know if I should actually touch the sensor with anything. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Normally I do not only post a link. Now I am going to do just that:

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cleaning+a+dslr+sensor

Cleaning a sensor is a dedicated process that needs to be done in specific working conditions, specific tools and solutions. So explore some of those videos and see if you want to do it yourself or send it to a service department.

Do not just watch one. Take your time and see diferent ones and you will be grasping which has a good methodology to do it.